# Python Virtualemv

Tags: python-3.x

I want to setup virtualemv in python in windows 10 but I am unable to do that I don't know why because I am a beginner. I already install get-pip.py in my python/tools/scripts folder and after that, I have also upgraded my virtualemv.

But problem is that when I want to run this command I am getting error C:\Users\Ravi\Documents\Python\my_virtual_emv>virtualemv emv --no-site-packages

'virtualemv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

please help me with that

Comment: Are you sure you are looking for virtualemv with a **m**? Never heard of that

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake but I have also tried virtualenv but still getting same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it may be a mistake, spelling virtualenv not virtualemv

Comment: Yeah, bro, I have tried with virtualenv but error still the same.

Comment: Are you sure you added to the path or import if you are using the python console?